# How to create UserData with box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am trying to add Userdata to a Body:

```
Body body = world.createBody(foo);  
body.setUserData(ObjectStuff);
```

And when I retreive the data, it will always return null.  I know that it is because of the way I have set the data.

Edit:

I would retrieve the data directly from the body, which now I see that doing that could potentially have problems.

```
Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>;
world.getBodies(bodies);
for(int i=0; i<bodies.size;i++) {
    Body body = bodies.get(i);
    Object foo = (Object) body.getUserData();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the user data in the correct way, show the code where you getting it from the `body`. Also make sure that you call: `fixtureA.getBody().getUserData();` and not just `fixtureA.getUserData();`. Fixture and body have different user data.

Comment: Or body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(obj)